# Unable to set state interface and pass props to other components in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript, I am making a weather app using open weather API, I am giving a call to API and setting the state of API response (`weatherData` here), but the typescript is not allowing me to pass the state as props to other component and gives error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'`. I previously made weather app using react js and didn't face any problem but this react typescript really sucks, very difficult to deal with types, please help me.

Am I not using best practices of typescript? please suggest any resources.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Search } from './Search';
import { CityAndDate } from "./CityAndDate";
import { Status } from "./Status";
import { TemperatureMsg } from "./TemperatureMsg"; 
import { SunriseAndSunset } from "./SunriseAndSunset";
import { Details } from "./Details";
import axios from "axios";
import './app.scss';

interface AppProps {};

interface ApiResponse {
  response: object;
  data: object;
};

interface AppState {
  weatherData: Object;
};

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weatherData: {}
    }
  }

  enterKeyPress = (searchValue: string): void => {
    console.log(searchValue, 'searchValue');
    const getWeatherDataByCity = async (city: string) => {
      const response: ApiResponse = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=#######&units=metric`);
      this.setState({ weatherData:  response.data });
    }
    getWeatherDataByCity(searchValue);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state, 'state')
    const { weatherData } = this.state;
    return(
      <Fragment>
        <div className="row justify-content-lg-end justify-content-md-end justify-content-sm-center">
          <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><Search enterKeyPress={this.enterKeyPress} /></div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center m-3">
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <CityAndDate city={weatherData.name}  />    // Getting error here
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row justify-content-lg-start justify-content-md-start justify-content-sm-center small-screen-container mt-5">
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><Status /></div>
          </div>
          <div className="row justify-content-lg-between justify-content-md-between justify-content-sm-center mt-2">
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-8"><TemperatureMsg /></div>
            <div className="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-8 sm-mt-10"><SunriseAndSunset /></div>
          </div>
          <div className="row mt-5">
            <div className=""><Details /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a type of `WeatherObject` with the properties defined and assign this type (instead of an ambigous `Object`) to your `weatherObject`.

Comment: Thanks @k-wasilewski, your answer has really helped me.